# Magento get product from page layout (like 1column.phtml)

Tags: magento, templates, magento-1.7, product

I'm using Magento 1.7

I've created a custom page layout (parallaxe.phtml)
A product is associated to this custom page layout.

I'm on the product view page, my custom layout page is showing.
I want to acces my product's informations directly from this page.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

returns `null`  :(

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your template is attached to a block of type core/template (or some other block that does not set a product variable.

You can access the product variable from registry by calling either `$product = Mage::registry('current_product');` or `$product = Mage::registry('product');`